# How can I disable the guest account?

Tags: greeter

I do not want to see the Guest account on my login screen.

How do I disable it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**A more convenient way to disable the guest login is:**

Open *System Settings* and navigate to *User Accounts*.
Then select *Guest Session* and unlock the settings by authenticating with your user password:

[image: Unlock]

You can now easily disable the guest session:

[image: disabled guest session]

Answer (score -1):

Open up the pantheon-greeter config file:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-pantheon-greeter.conf
```

Add the following line and save:

```
allow-guest=false
```

Done.